# ufw not logging all connections as expected

Tags: ubuntu, logs, firewall, ufw

I am trying to setup logging on ubuntu server 20.04.4 using ufw, but I'll take non-ufw advice as well.

I am running a test https server on port 20000 and want to log all connections to it. Here's what I did.

```
ufw allow log-all 20000/tcp
```

Here's my ufw status:

```
To          Action          From          
--          ---------       -----
20000/tcp   ALLOW IN        Anywhere         (log-all)
```

Now the only records I see in my log file (/var/log/ufw.log) are the "blocks" being generated from other rules. I am able to connect to the server from outside, and my test server runs fine (*delivers the content I need*). But I just don't see any records pertaining to this rule in ufw logs.

What might I be missing?

Edit 1: Since I cannot comment yet, I am reacting to @mashuptwice's advice here.

My ufw logging is on (low).

If I did

```
ufw logging medium
```

wouldn't that apply to all rules? I only need extra logging for this specific rule.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable logging for ufw. You can do that via:

`ufw logging on`

And set the loglevel via:

`ufw logging <loglevel>`

The different loglevels according to `man ufw`:

```
LEVEL may be 'off', 'low', 'medium', 'high' and 'full'. Log levels are defined as:

       off    disables ufw managed logging

       low    logs all blocked packets not matching the defined policy (with rate limiting), as well as packets matching logged rules

       medium log level low, plus all allowed packets not matching the defined policy, all INVALID packets, and all new connections.  All logging is done with rate limiting.

       high   log level medium (without rate limiting), plus all packets with rate limiting

       full   log level high without rate limiting
```

You can check the current logging status via `ufw status verbose`

```
╭─root@someserver ~ 
╰─# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured it out.

I had another rule in the firewall before my log-all rule.

```
To                  Action                From
--                  ------                -----
20000               ALLOW IN              Anywhere
20000/tcp           ALLOW IN              Anywhere       (log-all)
```

My log-all rule was not even being triggered. Once I deleted the prior rule, the logging is working as expected.

Thanks everyone for your attention.